# How to apply a filter to the pre recorded video file only for the certain duration?

Tags: gpuimage

1. Is it possible to apply a filter to the pre recorded video for a specified duration by modifying your code or by using any of the existing api’s you have written? Eg( Applying filter to the x1 - x2 seconds of X seconds video) Right now i refer to your SimplevideoFilefilter. 
   I also need to save the video.  It would help me to save time in cropping and passing the video to GPUimage as NSURL.
2. Is it possible to record the video at a FPS rate of 120(or 60fps) fps using your code, for iphone5s, iphone4s, and older devices?